# Error in dispose() Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dispose

i have created a selenium script in maven java, it opens a website and do some tasks, and sometimes it opens Firefox in one more new window automatically. so i want to handle such situation by closing all windows of Firefox. as you know driver.close(); will only close one focused window, so i replaced driver.close(); with driver.dispose(); to close all Firefox windows but it shows error in eclipse

```
The method dispose() is undefined for the type WebDriver
```

and i think no need to add my code here, because my question is how can i close all windows of Firefox? or how to use driver.dispose() ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`.quit()`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#quit--) method instead:

> `void quit()`
>
> Quits this driver, *closing every associated window*.

```
driver.quit();
```

Comment: is it possible to close all Firefox windows, but my selenium test should be continue...

Answer (score 0):

Use [`close`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#close--) if you want to close just the current window or [`quit`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#quit--) to closing every window associated to the driver.